# Showing Rails application structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. I have created a new rails app to try different basic rails commands. Like `rails g controller`, `rails g model`, `rails g scaffold`. But after a while, I kind of forgot what I have done.

Is there a command to show what I have in my application? sort of 
like the information right after I run `rails g controller C p1 p2`,
to display all things I have?

Comment: http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/

Comment: wait, do you want to see which controller, models or views have you created lately using the generators?

Comment: @CbaBhusal: yes, `rake routes`  is actually close:)  just want to know if there are any other more detail information to display. if there is nothing else, I will just live with `rake routes` :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this linux command if you are using Ubuntu or similar linux OS. Make sure you are inside your `project_directory/app`. Use the following command:

`find ./controllers ./models`

or

`find ./controllers ./models -type f -follow -print`

`-type f` means it will display real files (not symlinks)

`-follow` means it will follow your directory symlinks

`-print` will cause it to display the filenames.

This will list out all your controllers and models you have created.
If you want a `ls` type display, you can do the following

`find /dir -type f -follow -print|xargs ls -l`